# Handle custom exceptions using JQuery .ajax()

Tags: ajax, jquery, spring-mvc

Here is what my controller method looks like:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/com/uData.htm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody String getData(HttpServletRequest request, 
      HttpServletResponse response, @RequestParam(value="sn", required=true) String sn, 
      @RequestParam(value="serv", required=true) String serv,
      @RequestParam(value="date", required=false) String date) throws IOException{
try {
      Srring data =...;
      if(condition == false) {
         throw new IOException("my exception message");
    }
...
...

    } catch (IOException ie) {
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, ie.getMessage());
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        response.getWriter().write(ie.getMessage());
        response.flushBuffer();
    }

  return data;
}
```

And here is what my jQuery ajax looks like

```
$.ajax({
    cache: false,
    url: "/com/uData.htm",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {"sn": sn, "serv": selServ},
    success: function(dt){
    result = dt;
  },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      if(jqXHR.responseText !== '') {
          alert(textStatus+": "+jqXHR.responseText);
    } else {
          alert(textStatus+": "+errorThrown);
       }  
     }
  });
```

The custom exception message that is returned is not alert in my jsp
using the

```
alert(textStatus+": "+jqXHR.responseText);
```

How do I return the custom exception message ("my exception message") to the JSP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put it into the result of your method. Instead of returning `String`, return an object which has two `String` properties: `result` and `exception`.

That way, the client side `success` code can examine the exception.

Add more fields if you need more details (like exception type or additional information why the exception happened).

Comment: So, we can't use the error function in jQuery to show the custom exception?  Is there any way to push the exception message to the error function?

Comment: The `error` function isn't for handling errors in the server side code but for errors that happen while talking to the server (i.e. during sending/receiving the AJAX request).

Answer (score 0):

Try parsing the response.responseText into an object so you can pull just the ExceptionMessage (your custom exception message).

```
            var message = $.parseJSON(jqXHR.responseText);
            alert(textStatus+': '+message.ExceptionMessage);
```

My code sample uses the [jQuery.parseJSON method](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/) to extract the object from the JSON.